# How can I change the tooltips in my ng grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, devexpress, ng-grid, devextreme

I would like to change the tooltip name in my button 'Export to Excel'. I have angular directive (ng-grid). The directive config is :

```
var defaultConfig = {
                                    dataSource: {
                                            dataPath: "gridCtrl.getFilteredData(true)",
                                            deep: false,
                                        },
                                    bindingOptions: {
                                            dataSource: {
                                                    dataPath: "gridCtrl.getFilteredData(true)",
                                                    deep: false,
                                                },
                                            columns: "gridCtrl.getColumns()"
                                        },
                                    remoteOperations:  false,
                                    focusStateEnabled: true,
                                    hoverStateEnabled: true,
                                    allowColumnReordering: true,
                                    editing: { editEnabled: false },
                                    paging: { enabled: true, pageSize: 25 },
                                    pager: { showPageSizeSelector: true, allowedPageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100] },
                                    filterRow: { visible: true, applyFilter: "auto" },
                                    sorting: { mode: "multiple" },
                                    searchPanel: { width: 240, placeholder: $i18n.translate("lbl_search") },
                                    headerFilter: { visible: true },
                                    groupPanel: { visible: true, allowColumnDragging: true, emptyPanelText: $i18n.translate("txt_arrastrar_columna") },
                                    allowColumnResizing: true,
                                    columnAutoWidth: false,
                                    columnChooser: { enabled: false, emptyPanelText: $i18n.translate("lbl_hide_columns_here"), title: $i18n.translate("lbl_column_chooser") },                                        
                                    rowAlternationEnabled: true,
                                    showExpandAll: false,
                                    summary: {
                                            totalItems: [{
                                                column:0,
                                                summaryType:"count",
                                                customizeText: function (resourceInfo){ return $i18n.translate("lbl_total_items")+": "+resourceInfo.value; }
                                            }]
                                        },
                                };
```

[image]

The tooltip which I want to change is 'Export to Excel'.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to create an answer.  What is the code behind the grid?  What about the HTML?  What about the grid template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about [dxDataGrid](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/) so use export/texts for this as you can see in the sample code below

```
$("#datagrid").dxDataGrid({   
    "export": {
        "enabled": true,
        "fileName": "DataGridCusomText",
        "texts": {
            "exportAll": "Export everything",
            "exportSelectedRows": "Export only selected",
            "exportTo": "Export to excel or word"
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see in the image below

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! It is exactly what I was looking for.